# how to treat varchar zero-length as null in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, null

I know in SQL Server, a zero-length string ('') is different from `null`, but is there any way to determine whether it is a zero-length string or null?

The business requirement is:

1. If user input an index word, let's say `IN_DATE`, then match the `IN_DATE`;
2. If user input nothing for `IN_DATE`, then match every thing

I tested by using following statements.

```
DECLARE @IN_DATE VARCHAR(8)
SET @IN_DATE  = null
--SET @IN_DATE  = ''
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ISNULL(@IN_DATE, GETDATE()), 112) AS OUT_DATE
```

Neither null nor zero-length `VARCHAR` will bring me the expected result. But I tried the following query which works correctly.

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ISNULL(NULL, GETDATE()), 112) AS OUT_DATE
```

Anyone can tell me what's the internal logic of these queries? Thanks so much.

Comment: your difference (with @IN_DATE setted to null at least) come from the usage of ISNULL function. If you use COALESCE instead, you will get the same result (for NULL values) : see http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull for explanations.

Comment: Presumably, the user isn't directly typing the text into an SQL query window - hopefully there's some code sitting between the user and the SQL Server - it would be far better to perform the appropriate parsing/error correcting in *that* layer and then pass a genuine `datetime` (or `date`, `datetime2`, as appropriate) to the server rather than passing this wishy-washy string to it.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Thank you. I read the reference and found it's very helpful.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You are right. The ACTION layer will first receive the parameters from the VIEW layer. But for the case I asked, I have to write a query to handle the NULL or '' parameters because someone else is going to reusing the query, and unfortunately I cannot presume he is going to send perfect parameters.

Comment: But using a `datetime` rather than a string is a far better way of making sure that they send the correct parameters - you suddenly, for free, also guarantee that what they send you is a valid date rather than the string `last monday` (or `2014-02-30`). Embrace the data types and you have a lot less silliness you have to then find workarounds for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @PASSED AS VARCHAR(50) = NULL

SELECT 
  CASE 
     WHEN ISDATE(@PASSED) = 0 THEN GETDATE() 
     ELSE CONVERT(DATE, @PASSED) 
  END AS DATE_OUT
```

1) If NULL is used for passed then today's date is returned

2) If text '13/13/2014' is passed but not a valid date then again today's date is passed

3) If a valid date '03/13/2014' is passed it is converted into a valid date type

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer inspired me, and I use CASE WHEN LEN(@input) to identify null and zero-length string at one time when @input is not date format.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @IN_DATE VARCHAR(8) = ''
SELECT  
    (CASE @IN_DATE WHEN '' 
                  THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), GETDATE(), 112) 
                  ELSE @IN_DATE END) AS OUT_DATE
```

Comment: you can use this query for handling this situation.

Comment: why are you calling `ISNULL()` on `NULL`?

Answer (score 1):

To default to today if the variable is `NULL` or empty;

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(@IN_DATE, ''), GETDATE())
```

For *(2) If user input nothing for IN_DATE, then match every thing*

```
WHERE
   (NULLIF(@IN_DATE, '') IS NULL OR SomeField = @IN_DATE)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried the solutions. The first method seems cannot work because ISNULL() will always return the same data type as its first argument. The result is very strange: '10 27 20'. And as with (2) you mentioned, I think it will help me somehow, thanks very much. But when IN_DATE is set to be null, NULLIF throws an exception 'Date type of the first argument must be specified'.